# Narrow a query in Semantic MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

I fail to write a query displaying the relevant information in Semantic Mediawiki.
Let's say there are two main properties for an *author*: `Quotes` and `AuthorOf`, and one for a *book*: `HasQuotedAuthor`.

Suppose that there are three authors: **Coleridge**, **Byron** and **Dickens**.

- **Byron** and **Dickens** have the property `[[Quotes::Byron]]`.
- **Byron** has the property `[[AuthorOf::The first kiss of love]]` and `[[AuthorOf::The Dream]]`
- **Dickens** has the property `[[AuthorOf::A Christmas Carol]]` and `[[AuthorOf::Oliver Twist]]`.
- **The Dream** and **A Christmas Carol** have the property `[[HasQuotedAuthor::Coleridge]]`.

How can you build a query on the page of Coleridge to get a table including the authors who quote him and only the relevant books where Coleridge is actually quoted?

Comment: I can't really figure out what you are trying to do here. As faras i can understand, that query should only return authors?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to improve my question above. No the query should return the authors and only their books including the property hasQuotedAuthor.

Answer (score 2):

I created these pages and queries for you here: http://smw.referata.com/wiki/Coleridge

You are asking for any author of a book where `{{PAGENAME}}` (in this case Coleridge) is quoted. Your query would look like this:

```
{{#ask: [[Author of::<q>[[HasQuotedAuthor::{{PAGENAME}}]]</q>]] }}
```

and the result will be: `Byron, Dickens`

Or you could print books and authors at the same time:

```
{{#ask:[[HasQuotedAuthor::{{PAGENAME}}]]
  |?-Author of
}}
```

The minus sign before `Author of` indicates a reverse property. In other words we want to show authors having authored this book. We could also have used this query to create a list similar to the first one, by just hiding the first column:

```
{{#ask:[[HasQuotedAuthor::{{PAGENAME}}]]
  |?-Author of
  |format=ul
  |mainlabel=-
}}
```